# Add certain number of variables from one group to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a pandas data frame in which I have chunked `object`s of the same `type` into groups of a certain number (e.g., 3). For example, the group `ball_1` contains 3 unique objects from the same type: `soccer`, `basket`, and  `bouncy`. The remainder object(s) goes into group `ball_2` which, in this case, only has 1 object `tennis`.

For groups that contain less than 3 unique objects, I'd like to fill them with the first k unique objects of the first group. For example, group `ball_2` would be filled with `tennis` and then `soccer` and `basket` from group `ball_1`. So the goal is for all groups to have the same number of unique objects.

```
# chunk into groups of 3
N = 3
g = df.groupby('type')['object'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]) // N + 1
df['group'] = df['type'].str.cat(g.astype(str), '_')

# identify which groups need more objects
for name, batch in df.groupby(['group']):
    subset = df[df.group.isin([name])]
    batch = batch.assign(check = subset['object'].nunique() < 3)
    batch = batch.assign(need = 3 - subset['object'].nunique())
    needmore = batch.loc[batch['check'] == True]
    if needmore.empty:
          continue 
    print('{} needs {} more objects'.format(batch['group'].unique(), batch['need'].unique()))
```

Current df (this toy dataset with selected columns, but the real dataset has more columns)

```
     type  object  index    group
0    ball  soccer      1   ball_1
1    ball  soccer      2   ball_1
2    ball  basket      1   ball_1
3    ball  bouncy      1   ball_1
4    ball  tennis      1   ball_2
5    ball  tennis      2   ball_2
6   chair  office      1  chair_1
7   chair  office      2  chair_1
8   chair  office      3  chair_1
9   chair  lounge      1  chair_1
10  chair  dining      1  chair_1
... ...    ...         ......
```

Desired df (has objects added to group `ball_2`)

```
     type  object  index    group
0    ball  soccer      1   ball_1
1    ball  soccer      2   ball_1
2    ball  basket      1   ball_1
3    ball  bouncy      1   ball_1
4    ball  tennis      1   ball_2
5    ball  tennis      2   ball_2
6    ball  soccer      1   ball_2
7    ball  soccer      2   ball_2
8    ball  basket      1   ball_2
9    chair office      1  chair_1
10   chair office      2  chair_1
11   chair office      3  chair_1
12   chair lounge      1  chair_1
13   chair dining      1  chair_1
... ...    ...         ......
```

Comment: the groups that don't match the condition will be always filled with the first group? And the first group will always match the condition?

Comment: @MrNobody33, yes! I've also chunked them so that the first group, like ball_1, has the full set of objects (so the condition is that it contains 3 objects). And if ball_x needs more objects, it'll be filled by objects in ball_1. And if chair_x needs more objects, it'll be filled by chair_1, etc.

Comment: Just added an approach @psychcoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
def addfisrtgroup(x):
    missing=np.arange(3-x.nunique().object)
    typegroup=x.iloc[0,0]
    msk=np.isin(df.loc[df.group.eq(f'{typegroup}_1')].object.factorize()[0],missing)
    return pd.concat([x,df.loc[df.group.eq(f'{typegroup}_1')][msk]])


temp=df.groupby('group')
       .apply(lambda x: addfirstgroup(x) if x.nunique().object<3 else x)
       .drop(columns='group')


groups=temp.index.get_level_values(0).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)

pd.concat([temp.reset_index(drop=True), groups],1)
```

Output:

```
     type  object  index    group
0    ball  soccer      1   ball_1
1    ball  soccer      2   ball_1
2    ball  basket      1   ball_1
3    ball  bouncy      1   ball_1
4    ball  tennis      1   ball_2
5    ball  tennis      2   ball_2
6    ball  soccer      1   ball_2
7    ball  soccer      2   ball_2
8    ball  basket      1   ball_2
9   chair  office      1  chair_1
10  chair  office      2  chair_1
11  chair  office      3  chair_1
12  chair  lounge      1  chair_1
13  chair  dining      1  chair_1
```

Comment: This is great for individually adding `objects` :) Thanks! So sorry if I was ambiguous before (I realize that now) — but could you offer advice about how to loop your definition so that it's generalized to all groups? For example, if chair_x needs more objects, it'll be filled by chair_1, etc. In my example, it just so happens that the chairs divided evenly into 3. The above was a toy dataset but my real dataset is quite large and will have multiple other groups that need to filled by the first group of its `type`. But really thanks so much, again!

Comment: To clarify again, your current code will fill any other groups that are less than 3 with objects from `ball`. However, my dataset will contain other types like `table` and are currently being filled with objects from `ball_1` and not `table_1`.

Comment: Thank you! Does `typegroup=x.iloc[0,0]` rely on `type` being the first column of the df? Your code is not generalizing to my real dataset yet, but I suspect that it's because `type` is not the first column. I've attempted to identify the correct column with `typegroup=x.iloc[0,27]`, although this is not working. Do you have advice?

Comment: Try something like this:`typegroup=x.reset_index(drop=True)['type'][0]`